# "redirect" parameter lost after failed login in liferay

Tags: liferay

In liferay, when we navigate to a private page without user login, we are redirected to login page with "redirect" parameter in URL.

If the login is success, the liferay redirects user to a "redirect" parameter value, but if the login fails (let say because of wrong password), liferay clears the "redirect" parameter (because of the page reload) and because of that the "redirect" functionality stops working.

Any idea how to keep this parameter even after failed login attempt?

Comment: Did you check up on how the redirect param is being appended to URL and how is it lost on incorrect login?It should be manageable via some hook to keep the param intact in request URL

Comment: Can you provide example URL to see if it is standard link or rather struts path? Both are processed differently and latter had some related issues in older versions.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to save the existing redirect parameter in a cookie (when page is loaded) and then use that value before submitting the form. Haven't done it myself but I'd use a hook to overwrite the login.jsp. Just an idea.

Comment: Suggestions,ideas need to be part of comment first,a tried/known solution should only be used as an answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette